# unable to post vales from checkbox in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post, codeigniter-2

I am developing an application with codeigniter. My issue is iam not able to post value from second check box(checkbox in else condition).

View page

```
<div class="form-group">             
    <?php if($pro[0]['p_featured']==1){ ?>
     <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="featured" checked>featured 
     Product</label><?php } else {?>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
     <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="featured" >featured 
      Product</label> 
   <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

My controller

```
echo $this->input->post('featured'); exit;
```

> I am able to post value from first condition. But not able to POST
>   value from second condition

Comment: There is a condition `if($pro[0]['p_featured']==1){` for rendering checkbox, are you sure that your second checkbox is rendering

Comment: yes I can see the unchecked check box in my form. on inspecting that i can see `<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="featured">`

Comment: What you get when you print whole output by `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);`

Comment: getting every value other than `checkbox` value

Comment: Ok, There is no way that you will not get value of checkbox other then it is not inside the form tag.

Comment: But i am getting value when it is `checked`

Comment: are you checking the else checkbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156715/discussion-between-yadhu-babu-and-urfusion).

Comment: @urfusion 
yes
but when i change name attribute of second checkbox i am getting value

Comment: @YadhuBabu `echo $pro[0]['p_featured']; die;` and post the data

Answer (score 0):

try

```
isset($this->input->post('featured'))?1:2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Form elements of `<input type='checkbox'>` will not post a value if not checked. So, if the checkbox is in second condition and it remains unchecked when the form is submitted, then `$this->input->post('featured');` will return `NULL`.

If you were thinking to use the `value` property to determine which checkbox was output to browser that won't work because `value` won't be posted if the checkbox is not checked.

Consider this solution

```
<div class="form-group">             
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="featured" <?php echo $pro[0]['p_featured'] == 1 ? "checked" : NULL; ?>>featured 
        Product</label>
</div>
```

This produces a checkbox that is checked when `$pro[0]['p_featured'] == 1`.

Notice the `value` attribute has been removed. That attribute is not needed in this situation.

When processing the form submit you confirm the state of the checkbox like this

```
$feature_checked = NULL !== $this->input->post('featured');
```

The value of `$feature_checked` will be TRUE if the box is checked, else it will be FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="wifi" name="wi_fi" value="1" <?php if ($post['wi_fi']==1) :?>checked<?php endif;?>/><label for="wifi" >Wi-Fi</label>
```

Comment: if it will be marked before and it saved in DB, this box will be marked else unmarked :)

Comment: It would help if you added some form of explanation for your answer.